# i was wondering why is this stack and node thing not working saying "import node could not be resovled" same thing with stacks btw im using vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

[I keep getting this saying import stack could not be resolved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLgTM.png) 
I tried looking up how to solve this but still couldn't find anything
I'm using vs-code
this is my first time using stack overflow
I'm using python
this was a project form code-academy it worked there but when copy and paste to vs-code it gives me that.

Comment: Never post your code/error as images. Instead, copy and format by using Ctrl-K.

Comment: because you name your Python file `Stack.py`, you have a cyclic import, you can't import yourself

Comment: Your current file is named "Stack.py", modify your file name and make sure the file path to import is set correctly.

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT how to i modify the file path to import is set correctly

Comment: @YeLoWeS Please provide your directory structure and tell us what file do you want to import.